# Is there a way to increase dimensionality of pre-trained Word Embeddings?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, word-embedding

I am almost newly exposed to NLP research, struggling with NLP and Machine Learning techniques that are used in NLP.

The question that I'm dealing with now is if there is some method to increase the dimensionality of pre-trained word embeddings (like GloVe embeddings) from a fixed size 100 to let's say 512?

The reason I'm asking such question is that I used these embeddings to train RNN network with a pre-defined dimension of 100. Now, I have switched to self-attention mechanism (Transformers) where the model is highly sensitive to training parameters. So, I was wondering if I could somehow (for example, using perceptron, or maybe MLP) to transform 100d embeddings to a new space with 512d.

I googled this before asking here, but ended up with finding no reliable source in the end.

Comment: I assume you mean without retraining?

Comment: Yes, without re-training. As the data is medical, and for privacy reasons, I don't have access to them. @JPAlioto

Comment: Weird! Wondering who voted to close this thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to feed a `100d` embedding to a network that takes an input of dimension `512`. To do this, you need to project up the embedding vectors to a higher dimension. You can use a simple feed-forward/linear layer that takes in the input of size 100. Make the hidden size of the layer to be the desired size which is 512 in this case. Also, note that this should be part of the entire network that is being trained, ie., the feed-forward layer should be trainable.

Comment: Thank you @scarecrow. Actually, I was thinking about the similar way as you pointed out, but needed to check in with an expert if this is the right solution.